# How can I manipulate my Android fragment from within a subclass of SimpleCursorAdapter?

Tags: android, android-fragments, simplecursoradapter

My app uses Fragments in association with a ViewPager to create tabs.

On one tab, I use a ListView to display contents of my database in a table. I have extended SimpleCursorAdapter in order to perform some custom tasks on each row of my list (e.g., alternate row color, buttons, etc.). At one point, I want to click an icon within a row and have it switch tabs, but I am having issues accessing the FragmentManager and ViewPager from within my CustomSimpleCursorAdapter class. I can do this within the fragment itself (see the commented-out section), but when I switched to using the CustomSimpleCursorAdapter, I lost that ability.

So, how can I access my FragmentManager and ViewPager from within my custom class?

**note:** I have marked the location within CustomSimpleCursorAdapter.java where I am having trouble with

```
// THIS IS WHERE I AM HAVING ISSUES WITH:
```

**Home.java**

```
package myPackage;

public class Home extends Fragment {

    private View rootView;
    private CustomSimpleCursorAdapter mySimpleCursorAdapter;
    private ViewPager myViewPager;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout studentSwipeRefresh;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
        myViewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);
        studentSwipeRefresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.student_swipe_refresh);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View rootView, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(rootView, savedInstanceState);

        drawTheStudentView();

        studentSwipeRefresh.setColorSchemeColors(Color.parseColor(Constants.RED), Color.parseColor(Constants.ORANGE), Color.parseColor(Constants.YELLOW), Color.parseColor(Constants.GREEN), Color.parseColor(Constants.BLUE), Color.parseColor(Constants.INDIGO), Color.parseColor(Constants.VIOLET));
        studentSwipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                studentSwipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                drawTheStudentView();
            }
        });
    }

    private void drawTheStudentView(){
        DatabaseHelper myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());

        Cursor studentCursor = myDBHelper.getStudentsCursor();
        String[] fromColumns = {"_id","studentID","location"};
        int[] toViews = {R.id.student_number_textview, R.id.student_id_textview, R.id.student_location.textview};
        mySimpleCursorAdapter = new CustomSimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.student_layout, studentCursor, fromColumns, toViews, 0);

        // Replace the _id column with a student count
        mySimpleCursorAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
            @Override
            public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
                String counter = Integer.toString((cursor.getPosition()+1));
                TextView modifiedTextView = (TextView) view;
                if(columnIndex == 0){
                    modifiedTextView.setText(counter);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        ListView myListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.student_row);

        // I COMMENTED THIS OUT. THIS WORKS FOR CLICKING THE ENTIRE ROW AND HAVING AN ACTION PERFORMED.
        // Listen for somebody clicking on a Student ID, and process
//        myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
//                Cursor subCursor = (Cursor) mySimpleCursorAdapter.getItem(position);
//                String studentIDNumber = subCursor.getString(subCursor.getColumnIndex("studentID"));
//
//                StudentInformation studentInformation = (StudentInformation) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(getFragmentTag(Constants.TAB_INDEX_PATIENT_VITALS));
//                studentInformation.setStudendIDNumber(studentIDNumber);
//
//                myViewPager.setCurrentItem(Constants.TAB_INDEX_STUDENT_LOCATION);
//            }
//        });

        // Draw the list
        myListView.setAdapter(mySimpleCursorAdapter);

        myDBHelper.close();
    }

    // Pass me a tab index (see Constants.java) and I'll return a refrence to that tab.
    private String getFragmentTag(int tagID){
        return "android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":" + tagID;
    }
}
```

**CustomSimpleCursorAdapter.java**

```
package myPackage;

public class CustomSimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private Cursor cursor;

    public CustomSimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor cursor, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
        super(context, layout, cursor, from, to, flags);
        this.context = context;
        this.cursor = cursor;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        // Alternate the color of the data rows.
        View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        if(position % 2 == 0){
            row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(Constants.WHITE));
        } else {
            row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(Constants.LIGHTGREY));
        }

        // If the "Information" icon/button is clicked, set the information and switch to that tab/fragment.
        ImageView statusButton = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.student_status_button);
        statusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View myView) {
                cursor.moveToPosition(position);
                String studentID = cursor.getString(1);

                Toast statusToast = Toast.makeText(context, "Showing information for student " + studentID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                statusToast.show();

                // THIS IS WHERE I AM HAVING ISSUES WITH:
                // * getFragmentManager()
                // * myViewPager.setCurrentItem()
                StudentInformation studentInformation = (StudentInformation) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(getFragmentTag(Constants.TAB_INDEX_STUDENT_INFORMATION));
                studentInformation.setStudentNumber(studentID);
                myViewPager.setCurrentItem(Constants.TAB_INDEX_STUDENT_INFORMATION);
            }
        });

        // If the "Location" button is clicked, then show a Toast with the information.
        ImageView locationButton = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.student_location_button);
        locationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View myView) {
                cursor.moveToPosition(position);
                String studentID = cursor.getString(1);
                Toast statusToast = Toast.makeText(context, "Sending location for student  " + studentID + " to MESA", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                statusToast.show();
            }
        });

        return row;
    }

    // Pass me a tab index (see Constants.java) and I'll return a refrence to that tab.
    private String getFragmentTag(int tagID){
        return "android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":" + tagID;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I tried passing in FragmentManager and ViewPager references into the constructor of my CustomSimpleCursorAdapter, but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: do you use this cursor adapter in more than one activity, or just one?

Comment: @TerryWhite Just the one activity.

Comment: Simply pass a reference to the fragment in your adapter's constructor. Then you could access the ViewPager and the FragmentManager, of course you'll need to make some getter methods in the fragment as those references are private to the fragment.

Comment: @Luksprog You mean the context? Because I tried passing that in, and it didn't help.

Comment: When you create the adapter do this: *new CustomSimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.student_layout, studentCursor, fromColumns, toViews, 0);*. Then in the constructor of the adapter, you also have the fragment and the Context: *public CustomSimpleCursorAdapter(Home frag, int layout, Cursor cursor, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
        super(frag.getActivity(), layout, cursor, from, to, flags);
        this.context = frag.getActivity();
        // frag.getViewPager()
        // frag.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()*

Comment: @Luksprog Thank you for the tip, but it didn't work. trying "frag.getViewPager()" would not work.

Comment: It was obvious you would need to create that method to return the private ViewPager reference you had in the fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Create an interface for example:

```
public interface MyTabChanger{

    public void changeTabTo(int nextTabIndex);
}
```

**2)** implement that interface with your fragment.

**3)** inside `changeTabTo` call in your fragment you can use below code:

```
myViewPager.setCurrentItem(nextTabIndex);
```

**4)** change the constructor of your Adapter

```
...

public class CustomSimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private Cursor cursor;
    private MyTabChanger mCallback;


    public CustomSimpleCursorAdapter(MyTabChanger myTabChanger,Context context, int layout, Cursor cursor, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
        super(context, layout, cursor, from, to, flags);
        this.context = context;
        this.cursor = cursor;
        mCallback = myTabChanger;
    }

...
```

**5)** then in your adapter when you want to change the `viewpager` simply call `changeTabTo`. For example:

```
mCallback.changeTabTo(Constants.TAB_INDEX_STUDENT_INFORMATION);
```

I think this is the general and cleanest solution you can use. In this way you can use the `adapter` with any `Fragment` and `Activity` as long as they implements `MyTabChanger`.

Comment: That worked perfectly for changing the tab, but I also need access to the FragmentManager to pass information to that fragment: StudentInformation studentInformation = (StudentInformation) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(getFragmentTag(Constants.TAB_INDEX_STUDENT_INFORMATION)); and studentInformation.setStudentNumber(studentID);

Comment: This is a [design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern). you can use the ideas to solve a lot of problems. you must recognize them in your situation. I am sure you can also use above pattern for `FragmentManager`

Comment: So, you're saying there is no way to do what I want it to do? I cannot click on a button within a row of my ListView in my Home tab, and have it perform these two functions? That doesn't seem right.

Comment: No, I did not mean that, I meant in order to use fragment you could also use above idea. Create interface and implement that with your fragment. then ... . All I want you to do is first understanding the whole pattern and then using with your situation. You definitely use this pattern for your fragment.

Answer (score -1):

You can use cast the Context you initialize the adapter with to your activity (provided you use the activity as the context)

```
public CustomSimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor cursor, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
    super(context, layout, cursor, from, to, flags);
    this.context = context;
    this.cursor = cursor;


    //Where you need to...
    ((MyActivity)context).mViewPager.setCurrentItem()
}
```

Hopefully this gives you a good idea of what you need to do :)

Comment: So, I did exactly as you suggested, and I get a "cannot resolve symbol" on myViewPager.